# Unable to update state within componentWillReceiveProps method

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component which is updated by a parent component by passing a prop. Within the `componentWillReceiveProps` i would like to change a state (availableData) which contains the newly added data from the prop (newData).

The prop is named `newData`, and the state which is updated is named `availableData`.

When i attempt to access the `availableData` where i concatenate new (unique) data i get following error:

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'availableData' of undefinedInline JSX script:79
```

And the code snippet:

```
var DataList = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {availableData: []};
    },
    componentWillReceiveProps: function(nextProps) {
        var availableData = this.state.availableData;
        var newData = nextProps.newData;
        if (_.isEmpty(availableData)) {
            this.setState({availableData: nextProps.newData});
        } else {
            _.each(newData, function(_newData) {
                var isDuplicate = false;
                _.each(availableData, function(_availableData) {
                    if(isSameData(_availableData, _newData)) {
                        isDuplicate = true;
                    }
                }); 
                if (!isDuplicate) {
                    console.log(_newData);
                    this.setState({ availableData: this.state.availableData.concat([_newData]) });
                }
            });

        }
    },
    handleClick: function (_data) {
    },
    render: function() {
        var dataItems = this.state.availableData.map(function (_data, index) {
            return <DataItem data={_data} key={index} onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, _data)} />;
        }, this);        
        return (
        <div className="col-lg-3">
            <ul className="list-group">
                <li className="list-group-item active">Data</li>
                {dataItems}
            </ul>
        </div>
        );
    } 
});
```

Failing on:

```
this.setState({ availableData: this.state.availableData.concat([_newData]) });
```

**UPDATE**:

Solved by setting `var _this = this;` outside the loop and referring to `_this`, unfortunately all setStates are not being initialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` isn't the component in the context of your duplicate. You need to pass the outer most this to your `_.each`.

```
_.each(list, iteratee, [context])
```

Comment: So i basically added `var _this = this;` outside the `_.each` and refered to `_this` which solved the problem. Now another problem that i'm experiencing is multiple `setState` within my loop which is not being updated in the render. How can i overcome this problem with a `componentWillReceiveProps` function? Do i need to force updates?